# Hive - issues while starting

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have been using **Hive** for sometime now on Ubuntu while **Hadoop** is in Pseudo Distribution mode however today out of nowhere i am getting error while starting Hive shell.I have not made any changes in configuration at all -

```
Caused by: Meta Exception(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hivemetastore service is not running. You can start the service with the command below. This command is for installations made using packages.

```
service hive-metastore start
```

For tarball installations, you can start the hive metastore using the below command

```
hive --service metastore &
```